# test ending with error in my project

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

My test Class:
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    @LargeTest
    public class LoginActivityTest4  {

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class);
@Test
public void testContainsIntialViews() {


    onView(withId(R.id.Mot_de_passe)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.Identifiant)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.button_connexion)).check(matches(isClickable()));

 }
}
```

my error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.macuverie.mobile.vue.activity.LoginActivityTest4
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
 at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
 at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.macuverie.mobile.vue.activity.LoginActivityTest4" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file 
"/data/app/com.macuverie.mobile.test-2/base.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.macuverie.mobile-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/com.macuverie.mobile.test-2/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.macuverie.mobile-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
 ... 8 more

  Tests ran to completion.
```

[my package for test :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUBSV.png)

It is the first time which I test under android so about one wants to explain me what I had of the evil or what I forgot please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any third-party plugin? In my case I was using `android-aspectjx` and for obscure reasons it leveraged my test runs. Removing the line below from my build.gradle file helped :

```
apply plugin: 'android-aspectjx'
```

I would suggest you to check if you have any third-party plugins that could influence your issue and removing them one by one to see if one of them is the culprit.